# LaTeX3 \clist_sort:Nn -- How has this function been implemented?

Tags: expl3, latex3

I have recently read in the documentation of package `l3sort` about the usage of `\clist_sort:Nn` to sort lists.

I would like to know how and where `\clist_sort:Nn` has been implemented.

In `l3sort.dtx` I cannot find that.

Best regards.

Comment: It's in `l3sort`: I'm not sure what version you have but I can see it happily in the master code repo. (https://github.com/latex3/latex3/blob/master/l3experimental/l3sort/l3sort.dtx line 342.)